# Form select option, can't get the value and display text right

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I'm trying to generate a simple drop-down list (Laravel 5) where the value of each option is the ID of my businesslocations table rows, and the displayed text is composed of multiple columns data (address_1, address_2, city) taken from each row.

In my controller

```
public function create()
{       
    $businesslocations = Businesslocation::where('businesslocations.business_id', '=', \Auth::user()->business_id)->get();

    return view('client.create')->with(['businesslocations' => $businesslocations]);
}
```

Here's where i'm at in create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::label('businesslocation_id', 'Business location:') !!}
@foreach($businesslocations as $key => $businesslocation)
    {!! Form::select('businesslocation_id',  $businesslocations, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
@endforeach
```

It displays with value 0 :

```
<label for="businesslocation_id">Business location:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="businesslocation_id" name="businesslocation_id"><option value="0">{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;business_id&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;address_1&quot;:&quot; &quot;,&quot;address_2&quot;:&quot; &quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot; &quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2015-07-13 15:59:19&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2015-07-13 15:59:19&quot;}</option></select>
```

I'm looking for something like this value="id" and display text="address_1 address_2 city" for each option. Not sure about the syntax to get there.

```
<label for="businesslocation_id">Business location:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="businesslocation_id" name="businesslocation_id"><option value="1">Business location 1 - address_1 address_2 city</option><option value="2" selected="selected">Business location 2 - address_1 address_2 city</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query builder can use a "lists" method - so if you used sql that returned business_id as "id" and address1 + address2 + city as "name"

```
SELECT `businesslocation_id` as `id`, 
CONCAT_WS(" ", `address1`, `address2`) AS `name` FROM `businesslocation`
```

And then returned a list - similar to:

```
$businesslocations = Businesslocation::where('businesslocations.business_id', '=', \Auth::user()->business_id)
->get()
->lists('name','id'); 
(This is untested)
```

Then Eloquent will know what to do with that name , id and display it accordingly if you stick to :

```
{!! Form::select('businesslocation',  $businesslocations, null, ['id'=> 'businesslocation','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

So basically if you want to do it the Laravel way you need to pass name and id to the select dropdown.

That said, you could also add a function to your businesslocation model:

```
public function getFullAddressAttribute()
{
    return $this->business->address1 . ' ' . $this->business->address2 . ' ' . $this->business->city;
}
```

and then

```
$businesslocations = Businesslocation::where('businesslocations.business_id', '=', \Auth::user()->business_id)
->get()
->lists('fullAddress','id');
```

Hope that steers you in the right direction! Just a note that I haven't tested the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Used regular HTML to generate the options, works great.

```
{!! Form::label('businesslocation_id', 'Business location:') !!}
    <select class="form-control" id="businesslocation_id" name="businesslocation_id">
    @foreach($businesslocations as $key => $businesslocation)
        <option value="{{$businesslocation->id}}">{{$businesslocation->address_1}} {{$businesslocation->address_2}} {{$businesslocation->city}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
```